# Spatial spread of a relativistic particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, wavefunction, fourier-transform, dispersion

I am trying to figure out a picture of the wave properties of relativistic particle, e.g., particle produced at collider. It seems that the particle detected at collider have well defined momentum and energy.

Suppose a relativistic particle that is initially produced by a source within a distance $R$, and the production process is temporally localized to within a time $\tau$. The particle is characterized by its momentum distribution $A(q)$, which is centerd around a momentum $p$ (may be Gaussian). In space-time the particle may be described by a wavepacket
$$\phi_{p}(x)=\int \frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{e^{iqx}}{2\epsilon_q}A(q).$$

The produced particle have momentum uncertainty $\Delta p_i \sim\hbar/R$, after traveling a distance $L$, the momentum uncertainty will turn into a spatial spread. This spatial spread can be estimated by its velocity ($\vec{v}=\vec{p}/\epsilon_p$) uncertainty:

$$\Delta v_\perp = \frac{\Delta p_\perp}{\epsilon_p}-\frac{\Delta\epsilon_p}{\epsilon_p}\frac{p_\perp}{\epsilon_p} 
\approx \frac{\Delta p_\perp}{\epsilon_p}(1-\frac{d\epsilon_p}{dp_\perp}\frac{p_\perp}{\epsilon_p}) 
\approx \frac{1}{pR},$$

$$\Delta v_L = \frac{\Delta p_L}{\epsilon_p}-\frac{\Delta\epsilon_p}{\epsilon_p}\frac{p_L}{\epsilon_p}
\approx \frac{\Delta p_L}{\epsilon_p}(1-\frac{d\epsilon_p}{dp_L}\frac{p_L}{\epsilon_p})
\approx \frac{1}{\gamma^2pR}.$$
where $\gamma=\epsilon_p/m$ is the Lorentz factor. So the transverse size of the wavepacket after travelling a distance $L$ is thus $\sim\frac{L}{pR}$, and longitudinal spread is $\sim \frac{L}{\gamma^2 pR}$. The wavepacket is like a pancake now!

Now we set our detector at distance $L$, the particle excites the atom in the detector and its position is somehow determined. In the meantime, the wavepacket collapse into a narrower one. The particle continues on, leaving a track, from which its momentum is determined.

Comment: Why do you have $\epsilon_q$ in the denominator? What is it supposed to do? Are you studying this wavepacket and trying to keep relativistic invariance, or are you trying to study it in the context of a particular frame of reference? Are you considering an infinite plane wave, infinite in the transverse direction or longitudinal? Or is your wavepacket going to be about a macroscopically large Gaußian beam in the transverse direction? What about in the longitudinal direction? Your wave will spread in time with all these in mind.

Comment: Perhaps my question is ambiguous, I have rewrite it. I think I have got the right picture now.